# What is a word that means to not take the past into account?

Tags: single-word-requests

Short sighted is a good word that often means failure to or inability to take the future into account.

What is a word that means a failure to take the past into account?

Comment: Could be *amnesia*?

Comment: It is a bit of a stretch, but Markovian fits. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Markovian

Comment: I would describe them as _unholistic._

Comment: Not a single word, but Santayana's "Those who cannot remember the past are condemned to repeat it" is commonly cited in English. https://iep.utm.edu/santayan/